# Rails - passing a variable to string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is what's in my controller. I'm using devise and I'm trying to show take the user email and pass it into a where to find the specific family so I can display just the unique family controlled by the user.

I'm having an issue with the string interpolation. If I hard code the email into the query it works fine. But I want it to be dynamic. Thanks for the help!

```
home_controller.rb

  user_email = current_user.email
  @unique_family = Unit.where(:accountOwner => '#{user_email}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string interpolation you need to use double quotes `""`, like:

```
name = 'Some name'
puts "Hello #{name}"
# => "Hello Some name"
```

You see there `name` is defined within single quotes, but using the puts and interpolating the "Hello" string with the `name` variable, then is necessary to use double quotes.

To make your `where` query you can try with:

```
user_email = current_user.email
@unique_family = Unit.where(:accountOwner => user_email)
```

In such case isn't necessary to interpolate your `user_email` with "nothing" or trying to convert it to string, unless you want to make sure what's being passed will be an string, so you could do:

```
@unique_family = Unit.where(:accountOwner => user_email.to_s)
```

Or better:

```
@unique_family = Unit.where('accountOwner = ?', user_email)
```

That will bind the passed value for `user_email` to your query.

Comment: I'm getting <Unit::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdce0ef4da8>..    


My loop that is displaying this...

 ' <% @unique_family.each do |p1| %>
        <%= link_to "#{p1.familyname}", unit_path(p1)%><br>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <h3 class="h2-white pull-left">No Families Yet</h3>
        <% end %>'

Comment: Is that the `@unique_family`?, so, do a variable inspect `@unique_family.inspect`, and if you want to print the values from the Relation the you can use `each`.

Comment: Thanks. In the end this is what worked.   @unique_family = Unit.where("accountowner = ? ", email )     I think one of the issues was connected to accountOwner needing to be lowercased in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the normal `where` method:

```
user_email = current_user.email
@unique_family = Unit.where(accountOwner: user_email)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create association `User` <=> `Unit`, something like

in **user.rb**

```
has_one :family, class_name: Unit, foreign_key: :email
```